# R SQLite issue from Python

Tags: python, r, python-3.x, rsqlite

SO i am trying to run an Rscript from python, the rscript is using Rsqlite

here is the python call

```
subprocess.call(['C:\\Program Files\\R\\R-4.0.1\\bin\\Rscript', 'C:\\Users\\A\\Documents\\sql\\master\\test.R'])
```

here are the contents of the test.R script

```
test <- function(){
  library(RSQLite)
  
  db <- dbConnect(SQLite(), "A.db")
  
  tblist <- dbListTables(db)
  print("we made it in")
  print(tblist)
  
}

test()
```

When i run this in Rstudio i get the list of tables

when i run this in python i get the following

```
[1] "we made it in"
character(0)
```

which implies to me that the A.db file is not being accessed correctly through the shell

Any thoughts on why this might be the case?

Answer (score 0):

The answer turned out to be as simple as

```
setwd("C:\Users\A\Documents\sql\master\")
```

being added to the top of the script; when i added getwd() it was running from the python wd which seems obvious now